# Eclipse Javascript Editor wrong string recognition with Reactjs syntax

Tags: eclipse

When I write jsx in following format in default Javascript Editor, slash and grater than signs are interpreted as string. And when I press enter at the end Eclipse automatically adds " + "

I am using Eclipse 4.3.0.

How to fix this?

[image: Eclipse string problem]

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer I'm the author of [typescript.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Getting-Started)

I suggest you that you [install typescript.java 1.1.0](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which provides a [JSX support](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/JSX-Editor-Features) inside Eclipse. It provides a **JSX Editor** with syntax coloration for JSX (and JavaScript):

[image: JSX Editor]

Validation, Hyperlink, Hover, Completion is done by using TypeScript tsserver:

[image: JSX Validation]

Comment: Why -1 vote? I have forgotten to say that typescript.java is based on JSDT and fix the problem with automatically adds " + "

Comment: Some people downvote answers that look like promotion.  I've upvoted, because you've declared upfront your association, and it looks like a useful answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is not yet eclipse plug-ins to properly handle JSX syntax in eclipse.

There are plenty other IDEs that does support JSX:

- Sublime Text
- Webstorm
- Vim
- Atom
- IntelliJ IDEA